# Поиск минимального пути в графе с помощью жадного алгоритма bfs

Tags: python, алгоритм, поиск, графы

Есть такой код:

```py
from queue import PriorityQueue

# Filling adjacency matrix with empty arrays
vertices = 14
graph = [[] for i in range(vertices)]


# Function for adding edges to graph
def add_edge(x, y, cost):
    graph[x].append((y, cost))
    graph[y].append((x, cost))


# Function For Implementing Best First Search
# Gives output path having the lowest cost
def best_first_search(source, target, vertices):
    visited = [0] * vertices
    pq = PriorityQueue()
    pq.put((0, source))
    print("Path: ")
    while not pq.empty():
        u = pq.get()[1]
        # Displaying the path having the lowest cost
        print(u, end=" ")
        if u == target:
            break

        for v, c in graph[u]:
            if not visited[v]:
                visited[v] = True
                pq.put((c, v))
    print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # The nodes shown in above example(by alphabets) are
    # implemented using integers add_edge(x,y,cost);
    add_edge(0, 1, 1)
    add_edge(0, 2, 8)
    add_edge(1, 2, 12)
    add_edge(1, 4, 13)
    add_edge(2, 3, 6)
    add_edge(4, 3, 3)

    source = 0
    target = 2
    best_first_search(source, target, vertices)
```

Он вычисляет минимальный путь в графе по алгоритму [Best First Search](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E)

Сейчас он выводит нормальный путь `Path: 0 1 0 2`

Как переписать его так, чтобы он жадно находил путь по первому совпадению (по минимальному весу ребра)? Т. е. на выходе путь должен быть следующим: `Path: 0 1 2`.

Скриншоты для лучшего понимания прикреплю в комментариях.

Comment: [Нормальный путь](https://i.imgur.com/IF4OTs5.png)

Comment: [Путь по минимальному весу ребра](https://i.imgur.com/HOwGoCC.png)

Comment: Замените BFS на DFS. Среди рёбер торчащих из узла сперва обрабатывайте минимальные веса рёбер.

Comment: пишите дейкстру

Comment: @Neuro, было сказано "жадный". Не надо Дейкстру, надо помучаться. :)

Comment: а да точно, так и работает\